# Не настраивается поворот камеры в Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d

Вот скрипт для поворота камеры мышкой

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
[AddComponentMenu("Camera-Control/MouseLook")]
public class MouseLook : MonoBehaviour
{
    public enum RotationAxes { MouseXandY = 0, MouseX = 1, MouseY = 2 };
    public RotationAxes axes = RotationAxes.MouseXandY;
    public float SpeedCameraX = 2F;
    public float SpeedCameraY = 2F;
    public float MaxRotateX = -360F;
    public float MinRotateX = 360F;
    public float MaxRotateY = -360F;
    public float MinRotateY = 360F;
    float defaultrotateX = 0F;
    float defaultrotateY = 0F;
    Quaternion originalRotation;
    void Start()
    {
        if (GetComponent<Rigidbody>())
        {
            GetComponent<Rigidbody>().freezeRotation = true;
        }
        originalRotation = transform.localRotation;
    }
    public static float ClampAngle(float angle, float min, float max)
    {
        if (angle < -360) angle += 360F;
        if (angle > 360) angle -= -360F;
        return Mathf.Clamp(angle, min, max);
    }
    void Update()
    {
        if (axes == RotationAxes.MouseXandY)
        {
            defaultrotateX += Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * SpeedCameraX;
            defaultrotateY += Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * SpeedCameraY;
            defaultrotateX = ClampAngle(defaultrotateX, MinRotateX, MaxRotateX);
            defaultrotateY = ClampAngle(defaultrotateY, MinRotateY, MaxRotateY);
            Quaternion xQuaternion = Quaternion.AngleAxis(defaultrotateX, Vector3.up);
            Quaternion yQuaternion = Quaternion.AngleAxis(defaultrotateY, -Vector3.right);
            transform.localRotation = originalRotation * xQuaternion * yQuaternion;

        }
        else if (axes == RotationAxes.MouseX)
        {
            defaultrotateX += Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * SpeedCameraX;
            defaultrotateX = ClampAngle(defaultrotateX, MinRotateX, MaxRotateX);
            Quaternion xQuaternion = Quaternion.AngleAxis(defaultrotateX, Vector3.up);
            transform.localRotation = originalRotation * xQuaternion;
        }
        else if (axes == RotationAxes.MouseY)
        {
            defaultrotateY += Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * SpeedCameraY;
            defaultrotateY = ClampAngle(defaultrotateY, MinRotateY, MaxRotateY);
            Quaternion yQuaternion = Quaternion.AngleAxis(defaultrotateY, -Vector3.right);
            transform.localRotation = originalRotation * yQuaternion;
        }
    }
}
```

Я добавляю его на камеру и на обьект, но при запуске управление мышью не осуществяется.
Что не так?
Я делал все основываясь на этом [видео](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PoviwpPxs9M). Может, у меня какие-то отличия от него? (кроме названий переменных)

Answer (score 2):

Код лютое гавно. Не смотрите этот канал, автор даже не подозревает о существовании структур `Vector2`, `Vector3` и углов Эйлера. `Unity` видит впервые в жизни. Плохому научат.

```
[DisallowMultipleComponent]
[RequireComponent(typeof(Camera))]

public class CameraMouseController : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private Vector2 _speed = new Vector2(9, 16);
    [SerializeField] private Vector2 _veritcalLimit = new Vector2(-60, 60);
    private Transform _transform;

    private void Awake ()
    {
        _transform = transform;
    }

    private void Update ()
    {
        UpdateRotation();
    }

    private void UpdateRotation ()
    {
        Vector2 InputAxis = new Vector2(Input.GetAxis("Mouse X"), Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y"));
        Vector3 DeltaRotation = new Vector3(-InputAxis.y*_speed.y, InputAxis.x*_speed.x, 0);
        Vector3 NewRotation = _transform.localEulerAngles+DeltaRotation;
        NewRotation.x = GetClampAngle(NewRotation.x, _veritcalLimit);
        _transform.localEulerAngles = NewRotation;
    }

    private float GetClampAngle (float angle, Vector2 range)
    {
        angle = GetAngleFormat180(angle);
        angle = Mathf.Clamp(angle, _veritcalLimit.x, _veritcalLimit.y);
        return angle;
    }

    /// <summary> return angle in range from -180 to 180 degrees </summary>
    private float GetAngleFormat180 (float angle)
    {
        while (angle > 180f)
            angle += -360f;
        while (angle < -180f)
            angle += 360f;
        return angle;
    }
}
```